# Use an objects method as the call back to an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript Object called Company, which may be instantiated multiple times.

I want each Company to handle its own communication with the server, so that its ajax calls will be contained within the class.

So far I have:

```
Company = new Object();
Company.SendData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<some url>",
            data: <some data>,
            dataType: "json",
            success: this.ReceiveData,
            error: ErrorFunc
        });
}
Company.ReceiveData = function(data){
    alert("Received some data");
}
```

The Ajax works fine, and the server correctly receives the data and returns the response, but the call back function does not trigger.

My guess would be because it no longer has any frame of reference to what "this" is.

Is there a way that I can keep the functions attached to an individual instance of the class?

Comment: Check out the documentation on the `context` setting for `$.ajax`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different choices for how to solve this issue.  The crux of the problem is that you need to get the value of `this` set properly when your callback is called as it won't be correct by default.

In modern browsers, you can use the broadly useful `.bind()`:

```
Company = new Object();
Company.SendData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<some url>",
            data: <some data>,
            dataType: "json",
            success: this.ReceiveData.bind(this),
            error: ErrorFunc
        });
}
Company.ReceiveData = function(data){
    alert("Received some data");
}
```

Or, you can instruct jQuery to do the work for you with the `context` option to `$.ajax()`:

```
Company = new Object();
Company.SendData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<some url>",
            data: <some data>,
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
            success: this.ReceiveData,
            error: ErrorFunc
        });
}
Company.ReceiveData = function(data){
    alert("Received some data");
}
```

Or you can create your own stub function using a saved value of `this` (this is my least favorite option):

```
Company = new Object();
Company.SendData = function(){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<some url>",
            data: <some data>,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {return self.ReceiveData(result);},
            error: ErrorFunc
        });
}
Company.ReceiveData = function(data){
    alert("Received some data");
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thank you.
I have used the context option, which works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Company.SendData = function(){
 var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<some url>",
            data: <some data>,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {self.ReceiveData(res);},
            error: ErrorFunc
        });
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) SO post might help to understand.

**Update**

Fixed the example by encapsulating the function.

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested.

Comment: This doesn't actually work.  `self.ReceiveData` is the exact same value as `this.ReceiveData` at the time the argument is passed to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: I am from C# background and I hate this keyword in JS.

Comment: @MrGenius - once you understand the 5 rules for how `this` is set, it is not hard, but it is mysterious until you understand those 5 rules.

Comment: It's amazing that there are actually two upvotes for an answer that is completely wrong and does not work.  There are more upvotes for this answer than for the other answer that offers three correct options that all work.  Passing `self.receiveData` instead of `this.recieveData` doesn't do anything as `self` and `this` have the exact same value at the time the argument is passed to `$.ajax()`.  What you need is a method of fixing the value of `this` when the callback is actually called which this does not do.